# Storage exception has occurred. Object does not exist at location. Firebase storage error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have tried all the solutions posted on StackOverflow but my problem is not discussed there so I am putting up this question. In my case, the image gets uploaded in the firebase storage bucket but a new record is not inserted in the firestore and this error occurs.
My code:-

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Adding candidate........");
        progressDialog.show();
        final String fetch_name = name.getText().toString();
        final String fetch_age = age.getText().toString();
        final String fetch_number = number.getText().toString();
        final String fetch_area = area.getText().toString();
        try{image_path = storageReference.child(user_id+"."+getFileExtension(imageUri)).putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("Infor",uri.toString());
                                String img = uri.toString();
                                if(img!=null){
                                    storeData(img,fetch_name,fetch_age,fetch_number,fetch_area);
                                    Toast.makeText(add_candidate.this,"Added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                                else
                                    Toast.makeText(add_candidate.this,"Error ho gya bhaiya",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },1000);
            }
        });}
        catch(Exception e){Log.i("Infor",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();}

    }
});
```

The store data function looks like:-

```
private void storeData(String downloadUri, String fetch_name, String fetch_age, String fetch_number, String fetch_area) {
    Map<String,String> candidateData = new HashMap<>();
    candidateData.put("name",fetch_name);
    candidateData.put("age",fetch_age);
    candidateData.put("number",fetch_number);
    candidateData.put("area",fetch_area);
    candidateData.put("Uri",downloadUri);

    firebaseFirestore.collection("Candidates").document(user_id).set(candidateData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(add_candidate.this,"Completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(add_candidate.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Error:-

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. - Android Studio Code : -13010 HttpResu1t: 404

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Extremely sorry for that I have made the necessary edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the download URL from another location than where you uploaded the file.

```
StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(user_id+"."+getFileExtension(imageUri))
ref.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                storeData(uri,fetch_name,fetch_age,fetch_number,fetch_area);
                Toast.makeText(add_candidate.this,"Added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```